# Wrong path confuses apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using the following `RewriteCond` I want to have a rule for all files that are not images, css or js.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|svg|svgz)$
```

This rule works fine when the path to the file exists...

But when the path to the file does not exist (wrong path was given) **the rule continues even though the file ends with an extension from the list.**

How do I include in the rule to include paths even if they do not exist?

**Update:**

The solution was using %{REQUEST_URI} instead of %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem :)

When the path doesn't exist the `REQUEST_FILENAME` which maps to the real file on the FS isn't set.

Using `REQUEST_URI` instead solves the issue and treats all cases correctly.

**The correct instruction:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|svg|svgz)$
```